# How to use text instead of image on Android Tabbed Page

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms

I'm trying to follow along with the TabbedPageWithNavigationPage sample as shown here: https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-forms-samples/tree/master/Navigation/TabbedPageWithNavigationPage

However in their sample the Droid project does *NOT* have a settings.png page see: (https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-forms-samples/blob/master/Navigation/TabbedPageWithNavigationPage/TabbedPageWithNavigationPage/SettingsPage.xaml)...yet the application gracefully falls back to text only.

In my version (building from scratch) if I do not include the settings.png file, the Droid version crashes with a missing resource error.

I'm sure I'm missing something fundamental...any thoughts on what it might be?

Update MainActivity.CS and App.xaml.cs:

```
    [Activity(Label = "AppZero.Droid", Icon = "@drawable/icon", Theme = "@style/MyTheme", MainLauncher = true, ConfigurationChanges = ConfigChanges.ScreenSize | ConfigChanges.Orientation)]
public class MainActivity : global::Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.FormsAppCompatActivity
{
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
    {
        TabLayoutResource = Resource.Layout.Tabbar;
        ToolbarResource = Resource.Layout.Toolbar;

        base.OnCreate(bundle);

        global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init(this, bundle);

        LoadApplication(new App());
    }
}
public partial class App : Application
    {
        public App()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            MainPage = new AppZeroPage();
        }

        protected override void OnStart()
        {
            // Handle when your app starts
        }

        protected override void OnSleep()
        {
            // Handle when your app sleeps
        }

        protected override void OnResume()
        {
            // Handle when your app resumes
        }
    }
```

Update 2 App.xaml

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Application xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml" x:Class="AppZero.App">
 <Application.Resources>
  <!-- Application resource dictionary -->
 </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

Update 3 AppZeroPageCS.cs

```
using System;
using Xamarin.Forms;
namespace AppZero
{
    public class AppZeroPageCS:TabbedPage
    {
        public AppZeroPageCS()
        {
            Children.Add(new SettingsPage());
            Children.Add(new SettingsPage());
            Children.Add(new SettingsPage());
        }
    }
}
```

Update 4 SettingsPage.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace AppZero
{
    public partial class SettingsPage : ContentPage
    {
        public SettingsPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }
}
```

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml" x:Class="AppZero.SettingsPage" Icon="settings.png" Title="Settings">
 <ContentPage.Content>
  <StackLayout>
   <Label Text="Settings go here" HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" />
  </StackLayout>
 </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

Comment: Hi Webjedi! Can you post the code for your class that is instantiating the TabbedPage? I think I know the problem and will post my answer once I can confirm it after seeing your code. Thanks!

Comment: Did that help? I'm a XAML and Xamarin newbie so if I missed something you need to see let me know

Comment: Thanks Webjedi! Can you post the code from the app.xaml file too?

Comment: I added it Brandon. The example doesn't have an app.xaml....just and app.cs....which is also interesting to me. :)

Comment: Thanks again! I just need one last thing: can you post the AppZeroPage.cs code too? Sorry for all of the requests!

Comment: Updated. No need to apologize I appreciate all the assistance.

Comment: Haha- we're getting closer! Can you post the SettingsPage class too?

Comment: Done. I added the settingspage xaml too

Comment: Ok, got it! I'll write up the answer shortly once I am back in front of my computer!

Answer (score 0):

## Explanation

Your app is crashing because you are are assigning the icon in `SettingsPage.xaml`: `Icon="settings.png"`. But, you do not have a settings.png file in the `/Resources/Drawable` folder of your Android project.

There are two options to fix this:

1. Remove `Icon="settings.png"` from `SettingsPage.xaml`

   - This will use only text for your Tab and remove the Image
2. Add a settings.png file to each `/Resources/Drawable` folder of your Android project

   - This will add the image to your Tab

## Fix 1: Remove `Icon="settings.png"`

Here is the updated version of `SettingsPage.xaml` that excludes the `Icon` property:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml" x:Class="AppZero.SettingsPage" Title="Settings">
    <ContentPage.Content>
        <StackLayout>
            <Label Text="Settings go here" HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" />
        </StackLayout>
    </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

## Fix 2: Add Settings.png to `/Resources/Drawable`

Inside `/Resources/`, there are multiple `drawable` folders, and each folder correlates to a different screen-resolution density. You will need to create multiple `png` files of varying resolutions, and add the `png` file with the appropriate resolution to the appropriate folder.

[image: Drawable Folders]

Here are the resolutions for the tabbed page icons:

- 24 × 24 (mdpi)
- 36 × 36 (hdpi)
- 48 × 48 (xhdpi)
- 72 × 72 (xxhdpi)
- 96 × 96 (xxxhdpi)

For example, the resolution of the xhdpi `png` should be 48x48 pixels.

Xamarin has [additional documentation](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/application_fundamentals/resources_in_android/part_4_-_creating_resources_for_varying_screens/) about the Drawable folders.

Comment: So then why does the Xamarin example (first link) work? Their SettingsPage.xaml also contains the Icon="settings.png", their Droid app does not have the settings.png anywhere. Their navigation links just show "Settings"

Comment: You're right about the sample app. It could be that the error you're getting is not related to the missing settings.png file. Let's mark this question as answered to help future devs, then open a new question where you can post the stack trace and we'll debug it some more!

Comment: Your answer definitely does make the error go away for sure. My error does go away...so weird though.